# Why is it needed to import libraries in an interface

Tags: java, interface, libraries

I'm pretty new to Java, and sorry if this is a stupid question, and I'm a little confused why we need to import libraries in an interface.

I understand why you would need to import a library in classes, or main methods, as you are actually using the libraries. However, correct me if I'm wrong, in an interface, you're just declaring the methods with parameters without actually 'doing' anything with it. You only actually use it when you implement the interface in a separate class?

For example:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public interface ExampleInterface {

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);

}
```

Why would you need to import DataSource here?

Comment: Because you use that class in the method definition `setDataSource(DataSource ds)`! If someone implements that interface the class needs to know what exactly `DataSource ` is.

Comment: Note that in java you don't import code, you just import names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to import. You can use fully qualified names like `javax.sql.DataSource` everywhere instead of just `DataSource`.

But you need to do one or the other to specify the **exact** class/interface you're referring to. The compiler doesn't accept non-unique simple names for anything.

You might still need to use `FQN` if you're using classes/interfaces/etc. with the same name, since we can't import both due to naming conflict:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public interface ExampleInterface {

    public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);
    public void setActivationDataSource(javax.activation.DataSource ds);
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? We don't need to import if we use the `FQN`. It just becomes very tedious to keep writing a lot more than if we were to use imports.

Comment: Oh, I see. So it's to help Java understand the data type of the variable?

Comment: @OlivierGabison Not help. Define. Whether you're writing a class or an interface, you need to strongly define the types of parameters, return values etc. with import or using `FQN` you define that this is `javax.sql.DataSource` and not for example `javax.activation.DataSource`.

Comment: @swapnil Stop commenting on my answer. If you think you have something worthwhile to say, create your own answer.

Comment: Ok I removed my comments. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> In an interface, you're just declaring the methods with parameters without actually 'doing' anything with it

Yes, but you still declare them. So if you want them to be recognizable, you need to import the corresponding libraries. In your example you define a method :

```
public void setDataSource(DataSource ds);
```

in your interface. So unless you import `javax.sql.DataSource`, the type of the parameter you declare in `setDataSource` will not be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

It is to specify that what data type you are going to use in the interface, from which package, in one project there maybe different kind of data with the same name, so it needs to be explicitly specified, which type of DataSource is needed for further implementation.